# Python issue in cleaning data

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code I am currently using , I am relatively novice in the use of python. What I am attempting to do is use a sub selection of rcid's to conditionally change another column. The text file has all the rcid values I want to change in it, and I want to apply it to  va_yes column. When I tried this I get an error "NameError: name 'rcid' is not defined". I have tried this before with one decade , but want to have all of it cleaned in one go.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Adini\Documents\opec_pooled.csv")

rcid_1 = []
with open('C:\\Users\Adini\Desktop\\1.txt','r') as f:
  mylist = f.read().splitlines()
  rcid_1.append(mylist)


for cells in rcid:
  for rcids in rcid_1:
      if(cells == rcids):
          df.ix[rcid == rcids, "va_yes"]= 1`
```

Thank you

Comment: you assigned to the name `rcid_1` then attempt to use `rcid`

Comment: Looks like a typo. The variable rcid in `for cells in rcid` is not declared anywhere. Did you intend to use rcid_1?

Comment: I am sorry  I am little confused, are you talking about  `for ricds in rcid_1` or ` for cells in rcid` .  rcid is a column in the data , I apologize I am novice in this area @BenjaminDiaz @piRSquared

Comment: It is the outter first loop that you used undefined `rcid`.

Comment: How would I assign the column values to rcid ` rcid = df["rcid"] or rcid = df.column[2]`. Once again I apologize very novice at this @Sixiang.Hu

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `df` has a column named `'rcid'`, and you wish to add a column `'va_yes'` that is a `1` if the rcid is in `1.txt`, and `0` otherwise.

First, make sure that you have parsed `1.txt` correctly. Since you haven't uploaded a sample of it, I can't specifically tell you what to do, but you will want the rcids in a non-nested list. Assuming each line in `1.txt` is an rcid, your variable `mylist` is what you need.

You've loaded `df` correctly, and you can assign the `'va_yes'` column in 1 line:

`df['va_yes'] = df['rcid'].isin(mylist) * 1`

Comment: I think you are right I have `1.txt`  with a sample below

  `['629', '635', '636', '637', '638', '642',...]`

Each line in the text file corresponds to an  rcid , and I want to check it against the column `df['rcid']` . If the values match  then a `1` in the new column `va_yes`, and if not a `0`. I hope that makes , or I might just be a little slow in uptake

Comment: I have tried using your answer , but it does not work it creates a column with zero's instead of checking the condition.  I am not sure if it is my [data set](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7j7hjIdgYmIUk9RT3pBTTAzUVU), but here is a copy of it, logically it should work but doesn't. Thank you for your assistance I do appreciate it @kenwei

Comment: Your .csv rcid data has been parsed as integers, whereas the entries in your list were strings. You can either change the rcids in `df` to string types by doing `df['rcid'] = df['rcid'].astype(str)`, *or* convert the strings in `mylist` to integers, with `mylist = [int(x) for x in mylist]`, and then assigning `va_yes`

Comment: `import numpy as np import pandas as pd`
`df = pd.read_csv("file path")`
`with open('C:\\Users\Adini\Desktop\\decade1.txt','r') as f:`
   ` mylist = f.read().splitlines()`
 
`mylist = [int(x) for x in mylist]`
`df['va_yes'] = df['rcid'].isin(mylist) * 1`

It worked!!!!, data set is all clean now , thank you@KenWei